# Sabisu gem won't install "sabisu requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0". I'm running gem 2.1.9

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, cloudant

```
[user@host-02 ~]# gem install --local ./sabisu-0.1.1.gem
ERROR:  Error installing ./sabisu-0.1.1.gem:
        sabisu requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.

[user@host-02 ~]# gem -v
2.1.9
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does `ruby -v` return?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at gem version, that's why I couldn't see my ruby version was 1.9. I've upgraded to ruby 2.0.0 and problem solved!